# Understanding notation for a group decomposed as a disjoint union of double cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, lie-groups

Say we have a group $G$, with subgroups $W,B_+,B_- \leq G$ such that $G$ decomposes as:

$G=\bigsqcup_{w \in W} B_+wB_+=\bigsqcup_{w \in W} B_-wB_-=\bigsqcup_{w \in W} B_-wB_+$

To add a bit of conreteness to this, lets say that $G = SL(n)$, $B_{\pm}$ are opposite opposite subgroups, say the subgroups of upper/lower matrices, and $W$ is the Weyl group, which will be isomorphic to $S_n$. Then we have that $G/B_+$ and $B_-/G$ are flag varieties. The above decompositions are the Bruhat and Birkhoff decompositions. I'm not sure if this context is important for my question:

The author states:

We adopt the convention of writing:

$xB_+ \rightarrow^w yB_+$ if we have that $x^{-1}y \in B_+wB_+$

$B_-x \rightarrow^w B_-y$ if we have that $xy^{-1} \in B_-wB_-$

$B_-x \rightarrow^w yB_+$ if we have that $xy \in B_-wB_+$

Can somebody explain to me why this notation is chosen? What exactly is it communicating? I understand on a technical level, but feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you seen the Bruhat order?

Comment: Nope. And also, this notation makes a lot more sense since I made this post (for the Bruhat cosets anyway, the Birkhoff decomposition is still mysterious to me).

Comment: Interesting. What text are you working out of (or which one were you working out of when first writing this question)?

Comment: Section 2.1 of this paper requires a working knowledge of the Birkhoff decomposition.